# How to repeat find/replace command in vim

Tags: vim

If I do a substitution, for example:

```
:s/ov/xx/g
```

To substitute "ov" with "xx". However, if I press the `.` command on another line, it seems like it isn't repeating that find-and-replace operation. Instead it seems to insert a space when I try it again on the next line.

Why not? Is there a way to re-do that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat the last command made in command-line-mode (those made at the `:` prompt) with `@:` and then use `@@` to repeat the same change thereafter. Using `.` will repeat the last change that was made in normal-mode.

Comment: Thanks, what's the difference then between using `.` and `@:`. When would one be used over the other?

Comment: `.` is going to repeat the last change made in normal mode, whereas `@:` will repeat the last command given at the command line (`:` prompt).

Answer (score 0):

The builtins are `&` and `:&&`